# rails 4 - css files not loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading from 3.2 to 4.0.

I have some custom css files in my application.css;

```
/**
 * application.css
 *
 *= require custom
 *= require engine
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

when the page loads...the css file engine is not loaded. When i hit the refresh button the file engine is loaded and the styles are correct.

I am working in development enviroment.

What can i do?

Thanks...remco

Comment: Could please share your production.rb , application.rb and Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this working with rails 4, mine had to do with the sequence of files being called, changing the sequence solved the issue, but it was more of a hit and trial method, Check the resources in your browser, that might help